# SQLCMD to connect to Linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, sqlcmd

I'm getting a login error with the below `sqlcmd` to connect to a linked server:

```
SQLCMD -E -dlinkedserver -ig:\temp\script.sql -o g:\temp\test.txt
```

My linked server which is an oracle connects through the app account from the linked server.

Is there anything wrong with the above code, it tried to login to the linked server, run a scripts, and log to a file.

Comment: The linked server exists inside a SQL Server instance. sqlcmd has no idea what that linked server is. Reference your SQL Server instance in sqlcmd and then have your sql script reference the linked server.

Comment: The purpose is to connect to oracle server copy data to a sql instance

Comment: @user9394033 Then SQLCMD needs to connect to SQL Server first and reference the linked server *in the script*.

Comment: can you show an example pls.

Comment: Linked server (sql instance )  connects to oracle server and then executes a query and log to a text file this is the whole idea

Comment: Yes, I think we get the whole idea. I added some high-level pseudo-code to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the linked server defined in a SQL Server instance, then you need to connect to the SQL Server instance that hosts the linked server, and make sure that your commands reference the linked server objects using 4-part naming. The `SQLCMD` program has no idea what a linked server is, so it can't connect to a linked server directly.

Let's say your linked server is named `MyLinkedServer` then your .sql file should look something like this:

```
INSERT SQLServerDatabase.dbo.TableName(columns) -- SQL Server table
  SELECT columns FROM MyLinkedServer..[Schema].[TableName]; -- Oracle table
```

Or:

```
INSERT SQLServerDatabase.dbo.TableName(columns) -- SQL Server table
  SELECT columns FROM OPENQUERY
  (
    MyLinkedServer, 
    N'SELECT columns FROM [Schema].[TableName]' -- Oracle table
  );
```

And your `SQLCMD` would not say anything about the linked server name at all, because it gets information about the linked server from inside the script:

```
SQLCMD -E -S Server\Instance -i g:\...\file.sql -o g:\...\log.txt
```

Of course there are other ways to run queries against Oracle if you don't need to rely on (a) `SQLCMD` or (b) the linked server defined in the SQL Server instance.

Comment: SQLCMD -E -S Server\Instance -i g:\...\file.sql -o g:\...\log.txt---I will try this route since my sql query references the linked server